# If radio is checked then show a message action

Tags: jquery, radio-button, sweetalert2

I have a input radio in HTML

```
<input class="payment_processor_gocardless crm-form-radio" value="5" type="radio" id="QFID_5_payment_processor_id" name="payment_processor_id">
```

Normally the radio is not selected.
What I would like to do is, whenever I click that radio, I want a message to show via sweetalert. Here's my code:

```
$('input[name=payment_processor_id]”]’).click(function()  {
    if (($("input[name=payment_processor_id]").attr("value")=="5") ) {  
          Swal.fire({
sweetalert message goes here
        });
  }
});
```

Sweetalert is functional in other areas, so that's not my concern. I cant trigger it when selected the radio button. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `$('input[name=payment_processor_id]”]’)` is not valid, either add `"` or remove it also you have 2x `]` and only 1 `[`

Comment: Oops!! Overlooked it. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing some semantics error, have done modifications in your code.

```
$('input[name="payment_processor_id"]').click(function()  {
    if (($('input[name="payment_processor_id"]').attr("value")=="5") ) {  
          Swal.fire({
              sweetalert message goes here
        });
  }
});
```